# java.lang.NullPointerException in PageObjectModel Project

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have two pages, in one everything is fine, but in the other I get **java.lang.NullPointerException**

What is my mistake? Please help

LoginPage.java  -  all good

```
package page;

import Base.Base;;
import paths.LoginPath;

public class LoginPage extends Base {

    LoginPath loginPath = new LoginPath();

    public void ingresarPagina(){
        chromeDriverConnection();
        visit(loginPath.url);
        maximize();
    }

    public void iniciarSesion(){
        type("Qualityadmin", loginPath.txtUser);
        type("pass1", loginPath.txtPass);
    }

    public void clickEnBoton(){
        click(loginPath.btnLogin);
    }


}
```

HomePage.java - I tried placing the chromeDriverConnection() again, but I get the same error

```
package page;

import Base.Base;
import paths.HomePath;


public class HomePage extends Base {

    HomePath homePath = new HomePath();

    public void mensajeExitoso() {
        String mensaje = getText(homePath.txtMesajeExito);
        System.out.println(mensaje);
    }
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Base.Base.getText(Base.java:35)
    at page.HomePage.mensajeExitoso(HomePage.java:12)
    at step.HomeStep.mensajeExitoso(HomeStep.java:10)
    at stepdefinition.HomeStepDefinition.seMuestraUnMensajeDeExito(HomeStepDefinition.java:11)
    at ✽.se muestra un mensaje de exito(file:///D:/Project/aer/features/src/test/resources/features/formulario.feature:22)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Base.java - I don't think the error is in the Base class, but I put it anyway

Line 35: return driver.findElement (locator) .getText ();

```
package Base;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Base {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public Base(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public Base() {

    }

    public WebDriver chromeDriverConnection() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    public WebElement findElement(By locator){
        return driver.findElement(locator);
    }

    public String getText(WebElement element){
        return element.getText();
    }

    public String getText(By locator){
        return driver.findElement(locator).getText();
    }

    public void type(String inputText, By locator){
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(inputText);
    }
    public void iniciarSesion(String user, String pass){

    }

    public void click(By locator){
        driver.findElement(locator).click();
    }

    Double num1 = 20.00;
    String num2 = num1.toString();

    public void visit(String url){
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public void isDisplayed(By locator){
        driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed();
    }

    public void maximize(){
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

Comment: That message is telling you that the problem is on line 35 of Base.java, which is one file you haven't shown us.

Comment: So the value that you're passing to `getText` is null.  Pretty much what the message says.  That is, you haven't set `homePath.txtMesajeExito` to anything when you call the `mensajeExitoso` method.

Comment: why the homePath.txtMesajeExito is null, when I put the mensajeExitoso() method in the LoginPage class everything goes fine

Comment: It's not really possible to answer that from the code that you've shown.  You may need to use your debugger to figure this out.